# flutter commands doesn't execute from terminal, takes forever

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I installed VS, dart and flutter inside. Right now I'm following tutorials and learning stuff. Everything was okey, I was working from dart terminal. After I changed channel to "dev" (flutter channel dev) and tried to run app, flutter commands takes forever now, I mean when i press enter in terminal, it receives my command but does nothing, just blinking cursor. Only way out is "ctrl+c", to stop the process. So, I even cannot changes channel back. Even when i Type command "flutter channels", it hangs... 
I'm working on windows

I tried restarting VS, PC, reinstalling dart and flutter. non of them works for me.

[image]

Comment: Run any command with the `-v` option so Flutter prints logging information.

Comment: I tried that too, but terminal just takes command and then nothing happens :) even with -v

Comment: make sure to add flutter to your PATH

Answer (score 4):

I also have the same problem. The reason for this problem is version conflict between dart sdk and flutter sdk. Try the below options,

**Option 1:**

- Close your ide,restart the terminal
- Remove the cache folder from **\flutter_sdk\flutter\bin** and run **flutter doctor** command in terminal. This will try to re-download dart sdk.

**Option 2:**
 - Try to upgrade the flutter sdk version. updating via command line is not possible. So download the updated flutter sdk and replace it in current file location.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, just misread the docs. The mistake I was making was that it says-
**Extract the zip file and place the contained flutter in the desired installation location for the Flutter SDK (for example, C:\src\flutter; do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges).**
which I read as install in C:\Program Files.

*Thus extracting the zip file in some accessible location like the one specified should work.*

Answer (score 0):

Check folder and directory ownership and rights on fluter sdk directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that for some reason `git` (through VS Code) was locking `%FLUTTER_DIR%/bin/cache/flutter.bat.lock`.

It's easy to diagnose this by adding an `ECHO "trying to acquire lock"` right before the `CALL` line after the `:acquire_lock` line (currently [line 44](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/bc49cd1bcab51c491789e36dbbc4b53ca4d49dc6/bin/internal/shared.bat#L44)) into the `bin/internal/shared.bat` file.

Answer (score -1):

Place the flutter directory outside the C:\Program Files worked for me.